# I want to decript a Sql Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, encryption

[image: Sql Database]

I have been given a project to take over, my new client has given me all the files that where used to run the MLM website from the previous developer, my client asked me to decrypt the admin password. Someone help me go about this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: That seems to me like a hash value of a password. Hash functions are designed to be irreversible. I don't think it is feasible to get the original password. You can however change the password by replacing the hashed value to a hash of new password

Answer (score 1):

Dont waste time trying to unhash a hash

Just create a new user account with a password. Then copy/paste the new accounts hashed password into the Admin accounts password column. Using an UPDATE query of course.

The password for the admin account will now be whatever password you used for the new account.

Then delete the new account.

Comment: Thank you, let me try your option,

Comment: i have created a new admin user and inserted a new normal password but when i try to login the password doesn't work, will be glad for any further assistance

Comment: WHat do you mean by a _new normal password_